# Why isn't this running?

Tags: javascript

I have this code below:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Eloquent Javascript Ex 2 </title>

<script language = "javascript">

    /*
    function twoPowerTen()
    {
        var result = 1;
        var counter = 0;

        while( counter < 10 )
        {
            result = 2 * result;
            document.writeln( result );
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }   

    int limit = 1;

    for( int y = 0; y < 5; y++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < limit; x++ )
        {
            System.out.print( "*" );
        }
        System.out.println();
        limit = limit + 1;
    }
    */

    function drawTriangle()
    {
        var limit = 1;

        for( var y = 0; y < 5; y++ )
        {
            for( var x = 0; x < limit; x++ )
            {
                document.write( "*" );
            }
            document.write( "<br>" );
            limit = limit + 1;
        }
    }

    function whileDrawTriangle()
    {
        var limit = 1;
        var x, y = 0;

        while( y < 5 )
        {
            while( x < limit )
            {
                document.write( "*" );
                x++;
            }
            limit = limit + 1;
            y++;
        }
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type = "button" value = "Draw # Triangle" onClick = "whileDrawTriangle()" />
</body>


</html>
```

which doesn't seem to want to run when I hit the button - it's suppose to print a triangle of astericks to the screen. BTW I know the HTML isn't well constructed but the point is to just implement basic javascript as Im getting to grips with it's fundamentals.

What's the problem?

Comment: Does your browser show any JavaScript errors?  For example, if you run this in Firefox with Firebug enabled do any messages appear on the debugging console?

Comment: When you say it isn't running - you mean that `"HelloWorld"` doesn't get written to the document when the button is clicked?  And are you seeing any Javascript errors in your browser's error console?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `drawTriangle()` instead of `whileDrawTriangle()`?

Comment: In your whileDrawTriangle method you aren't initializing x to anything.

Comment: Your `drawTriangle()` function is never actually executed because it isn't called anywhere.

Comment: My guess is that `x < limit` will error up since `x` isn't defined to anything (you only set `y = 0`. `var x, y = 0` means "create variable X and create variable Y and set the value of Y to 0". Didn't you mean `var x = 0, y = 0;`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo yeh that's what I meant - simple mistake to let slip through :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize you variable x to 0;

Answer (score 2):

Your `drawTriangleMethod` is never called, you can just add a button to call it, or change your `onClick` to call that function. As for your `whileDrawTriangle` method you are only initializing your *y* variable to 0, while *x* is remaining `undefined` and therefore when it comes to the loop it *fails* the test `x < limit`.

If you want to initialize both *x* and *y* you need to do so explicitly

For example

```
 var x = 0, y= 0;
```

Here's a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uzavod/1/edit)

Comment: yeh i know that now, just starting with Javascript so was messing around with variable declaration and assignment. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you change your code to `onClick = "drawTriangle()"` instead of `onClick = "while DrawTriangle()"` it works fine.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4gMwd/)**